# Post dates web api custom format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

This is a nightmare (at least I can’t find an easy way), I have searched for hours and really can’t find my solution.

How do you handle dates in a custom format in web api? I need DD/MM/YYYY format

I can’t post my dates since my api wants them to be in the default format MM/DD/YY, one solution would be to parse all my dates via JavaScript to the format my api needs it, but for real? Isn’t it a cleaner way?

How can I make my api knows my format?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195570/asp-net-web-api-posting-uk-date-formats) post, and it says it does not work for posting. And no solution yet.

Am I in the wrong way? Too many up votes for the question, and not even a good answer!

Comment: Why not use a string and format it to whatever format you want? yourDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") should do it.

Answer (score 1):

By default, as JSON formatter, in Web.Api, used Json.NET serializer. Json.NET writes dates in [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) format. Dates in UTC are written with a "Z" suffix. Dates in local time include a time-zone offset. For example:

```
2012-07-27T18:51:45.53403Z         // UTC
2012-07-27T11:51:45.53403-07:00    // Local
```

You can override [serrializer date time settings](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html) by setting the DateFormatString property in web api configuration section:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
}
```

Also, probably, you will need to change thread culture settings in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    var newCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
    newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm";
    newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss";
    newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "-";
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
}
```